# Get Originating device(physical device) info for Packets trapped on Bridge

Tags: linux, bridge, socket, vlan

Lets assume below given is the set of net devices that my frame is intended to traverse over.

eth0(1) -> bond0(2) -> bridge(3) -> vlan100(4). >>> (number) is the ifindex for each netdevice

I have created a  RAW socket ( not binded to any interface) , attached with a socket filter to trap only a specific set of packets.

> I am getting a copy of frame trapped from each of the netdevice.
>   Is this expected?

Printing from.sll_ifindex for each trapped packet.

```
frame trapped from eth0 has from.sll_ifindex=1 
frame trapped from bond0 has from.sll_ifindex=2 
frame trapped from bridge has from.sll_ifindex=3 
frame trapped from vlan100 has from.sll_ifindex=4
```

Now I set the following socket option PACKET_ORIGDEV , I get the following result

```
frame trapped from eth0 has from.sll_ifindex=1
frame trapped from bond0 has from.sll_ifindex=1   >> acceptable since the originating device is eth0 whose ifindex is 1.
frame trapped from bridge has from.sll_ifindex=3  >> why is this not set to 1?
frame trapped from vlan100 has from.sll_ifindex=3 >> why is this not set to 1?
```

can someone help me understand the role played by PACKET_ORIGDEV socket option in the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The way that the frame transitions from `bond0` to `bridge` inside the kernel is different from the other two transitions. Instead of looping around for [`another_round`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/dev.c?h=v5.6#n5013) inside `__netif_receive_skb_core()`, the frame is forwarded inside `br_handle_frame_finish()`. The `orig_dev` information is not preserved by that call path. I think the input port is recorded only long enough to make it available to some netfilter hooks of the bridge family. It's not available to user space.

PACKET_ORIGDEV, [when it was introduced](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/core?h=v5.6&id=80feaacb8a6400a9540a961b6743c69a5896b937), was meant to cover encapsulation cases. It could be argued that it should work for bridging too but it doesn't look to me like a change that can be implemented lightly. Some of the involved functions are hot in the receive path.